# Fire-and-forget std::thread objects cleaning themselves up

Tags: c++, multithreading

When implementing a service, etc, there may be a need for fire-and-forget functionality where one creates a thread and leaves it to its own devices. However, one needs to keep the `std::thread` object around somewhere to prevent it going out of scope, but when the thread completes there is no neat `delete this` support, and even if there was, that's going to be a problem for non-pointer allocations. Similarly, higher-level libraries may have `Timer` objects, where a one-shot timer may be fired off but needs to be cleaned up when done.

One can perhaps keep a collection of `std::thread` and `Timer` objects, and every so often go through the list and delete the finished objects, but that seems bothersome. Is there some useful idiom for managing these kinds of temporaries?

<sub>My immediate solution has been to use a combination of `std::mutex` and `std::atomic` to get my service to return `BUSY` so I only ever have one thread around, but that feels like a Code Smell</sub>

Comment: C++ library is very limited in terms of multi-threading programming, better use ready-to-use timers and tasks which are available in different crossplatform libraries. Otherwise you will need to build a thread pool and whole infrastructure around it yourself.

Comment: boost::asio, as well as being a reactive async io framework, is also an asynchronous task manager.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what std::thread::detach() is for -- if you want the thread to be "fire and forget", then you call `detach` on it after creating it.  This causes the std:thread object to no longer refer to the actual thread of execution, so you can destroy the std::thread and is has no effect on the execution.

Answer (score 1):

In case of a lot fire-and-forget functionality you may consider using `Thread Pool`. Creating and destroying of threads have overheads, and a lot of it may eat your RAM in RT. Thread Pool fire up for you X threads ahead for you, that will manage every "fire-and-forget" thread for you.

[A simple Thread Pool that solve the problem for me](https://github.com/progschj/ThreadPool).

`std::mutex` isn't related to managing threads' resources, it's related to synchronize threads.